# Flyway on AlwaysOn

Tags: sql-server, alwayson

We are trying to use the Flyway API to create an SQL Job on both MSSQL AlwaysOn  replicas.

most of the migration should execute against the primary replica.

But, how can we execute the sql script file to create the job on both replicas?

Comment: This question is too broad in this for in [so.se], but might make sense in [dba.se]. Anyways, you might want to share more information, make it more clear. Showing that you put some effort into solving your problem by sharing the results of your research, example code or an example helps a lot. Please read [ask] in [help] for more information.

Comment: since the mssql alwaysON is configured with a listener (pointing to a primary replica). What is the best usage to make the migration execute on the secondary? as all the migration are duplicated across all replicas, JOBs are not replicated. Assuming we have 20 migrations, which the AlwaysOn will replicate, but one of them is a new created job that is not replicated. How do you suggest to apply such migrations?